# Troubleshoot to implement compareTo method

Tags: java

I have this class called Pair:

```
public class Pair<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> , Comparable<Pair<K,V>>{

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(){}

    public Pair(K _key, V _value){
        key = _key;
        value = _value;
    }

    //---Map.Entry interface methods implementation
    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V _value) {
        return value = _value;
    }
    ///---Map.Entry interface methods implementation

    @Override
    // if return value negative passed value is bigger
    // if return value positive passed value is smaller
    // if return value is zero values is equal
    public int compareTo(Pair<K, V> o) {
        V val1 = o.getValue();
        V val2 = this.getValue();

        // how to make compare between values(to check if val1 is bigger or equal to val2 and vice versa ) 
    }
}
```

As you can see class `Pair` contains `Key` and `Value` properties.I need to compare between the value properties and return int value according to result of the comparison.

In class I try to implement `compareTo` method.But I don't know to to compare generic values.

How can I implement comparison of values in compare to method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to compare `V`,
it needs to be comparable.
Change the declaration of `Pair` to make it so with this added constraint on `V`, like this:

```
class Pair<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Map.Entry<K, V>, Comparable<Pair<K, V>> {
```

And then you will be able to write `compareTo` like this:

```
public int compareTo(Pair<K, V> o) {
  V val1 = o.getValue();
  V val2 = this.getValue();

  return val1.compareTo(val2);
}
```

To explain a bit more... In this declaration, we don't know anything at all about `T`:

```
class Item<T> {
```

Since we don't know anything about it, values of type `T` within this class only have the methods of `Object`, nothing else.

If you write like this, we add information about `T`:

```
class Item<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

Here we know that `T` extends `Comparable<T>`,
so values of type `T` within this class have the methods of `Comparable<T>`,
that is `compareTo(T other)`.

Comment: Janos, thanks for post. Can you please give brief explanation  of this V extends Comparable<V> row.I just cant understand why it's works.

Comment: @Michael I added more explanation, I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for explanation.As I understand this row  "T extends Comparable<T>" make T Comparable! Or it's only check whether the T is comparable?

Comment: @Michael it doesn't "check". It requires it to be so. The compiler will not let you use a value for `T` that is not comparable.

Comment: ok... so for exampe if my T is value type int for example I will get error?

Comment: `int` is comparable, so that won't be an error. Anything not comparable will be an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compareTo` of `V`, as long as `V` implements `Comparable` interface, relying the comparison to the classe which will be used as value of the `Pair`:

```
public int compareTo(Pair<K, V> o) {
    V val1 = o.getValue();
    V val2 = this.getValue();

    return val1.compareTo(val2); 
}
```